# Closure Inverse for Proving $Z(G)\leq G$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Can someone tell me whether my closure inverse part for showing that $Z(G)=\left \{ x\in G:gx=xg\; for \;all\; g\in G \right \}\leq G$ is correct? I used the one-step subgroup test.

Closure inverse: Let $x,y^{-1}\in Z(G)$. Then $xy^{-1}\in G$. Then $gx=xg$ and $gy^{-1}=y^{-1}g$ for all $g\in G$. Then $gxy^{-1}=xgy^{-1}$ or $gxy^{-1}=xy^{-1}g$. Then $xy^{-1}\in Z(G)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You should let $y\in Z(G)$ and not $y^{-1}\in Z(G)$.

But it is true that $y\in Z(G)$ implies $y^{-1}\in Z(G)$. This is because for $g\in G$, we have $gy=yg$. Multiplying $y^{-1}$ on both sides, we get $y^{-1}g=gy^{-1}$ which conclude that $y^{-1}\in Z(G)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I state that $y\in Z(G)$ and use the arguments you said to conclude $y^{-1}\in Z(G)$ then carry on with the solution I made?

Comment: @numericalorange Yes you are right.

Comment: Maybe you want to multiply by $y^{-1}$ on both sides, not by $g^{-1}$?

Comment: @zipirovich You are right. The answer is corrected. Thanks!